# Error 500 Internal Server when get data using CURL php?

Tags: php, facebook, curl, facebook-comments

```
$query = "https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?format=JSON&query=";
$urls = array('about 500 link');
foreach ($urls as $url)
{
    $query .= urlencode("select post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time from comment where object_id in (select comments_fbid from link_stat where url ='$url')"); 
    $query .= "&pretty=1";

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $query);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT ,900); 
    $data = curl_exec($ch); 
    $response = json_decode($data, true);
    echo '<pre>';print_r($response);echo '</pre>';
    curl_close($ch);
}
```

When I run this code while there are about 500 links in `$urls` array, I get the an error as the result: `ERROR 500 - Internal Server Error`, but `$urls` contain only 5 links, there is no error. How do I get the content of all 500 links without getting a timeout?

Comment: 'When run code about 500 link' means that you run the code with `$urls` containing a set of 500 urls ?

Comment: For me the problem was with URL. I added trailing slash (/) at the end of URL & it worked. Don't know wether it's correct & Facebook treats it as same url?

Answer (score 2):

It's not curl error, it's your server error, because there is a limit to request duration. Requesting 500 pages takes awhile, and your script terminates. Try the following:

1. Set `set_time_limit(200);` or more
2. Run the script by using SSH connection, there's no timeout at all
3. Use `curl_multi_init` to do multiple request in parallel